# How to catch mouse click on RichFaces notifyMessage element?

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

I have RichFaces notify message element like

```
<rich:notifyMessages sticky="true" showCloseButton="false"/>
```

I want to implement ability to close notification popup by mouse click. Of course I can use showCloseButton="true", but I think little cross in top right corner of popup is not so comfortable to use. Is there any way to catch mouse click event above notifyMessage element?

RichFaces version is 4.2.1.Final

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User [Makhiel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21309500/2064242) was on the right way. Actually you should add click handler for div with class *rf-ntf-cls*, description of all used classes could be found [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/nightly_4_2_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Output_and_messages.html#sect-Component_Reference-richnotify-Style_classes_and_skin_parameters).

The main problem is that such popup elements could be added after page was ready, so you should add click handlers after popup was added.

In my case I called function

```
jQuery('.rf-ntf-cnt').click(function(){jQuery(this).css({visibility:'hidden'})})
```

in the end of the call which produced popup. I'm not a guru of js and I'm not sure that this  is the best way for close popup, but I think that idea is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest is this:

```
<rich:notifyMessages … onclick="$(this).find('.rf-ntf-cls').triggerHandler('click');"/>
```

RichFaces use the [Pines notify](http://pinesframework.org/pnotify/) plugin but the messages don't seem to support this "remote" closing directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually `<rich:notifyMessages/>` doesn't produce clickable element itself, in code it's just `<span class="rf-ntf-msgs" ... ></span>` without content or any clickable area. Generated div with popup like `<div class="rf-ntf-cls" ... >...</div>` placed in the end of page, and contains absolute position, and we should insert click handler in other way.

Comment: You are right it doesn't produce a clickable element but that doesn't matter. The `@onclick` is applied to the generated messages, not to the empty span.